# Value getting rounded up by CFQueryParam

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a self-submitting form, whose data gets used in a cfquery after it is submitted. I'm having a problem when the user submits a decimal rather than an integer.

This is for tires sizes

```
<select>
    ...
    <option value="19.0">R19</option>
    <option value="19.5">R19.5</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then if the form is submitted, the results are passed on to a cfquery to show results only for that size.

```
<cfif form.size gt 0 > 
    AND ts.decDiameter = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#form.size#" />
</cfif>
```

This works perfectly for whole numbers, but when I select 19.5, it brings me back the results for 20. It is rounding up. Something weird with the cfqueryparam. It is transforming the result into a numeric value, but it is rounding it up to the next integer.

Comment: http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/cfparam-sql-server-and-datatypes-89 -- You have to put a scale in there.

Comment: @Chester - You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the scale parameter.

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" scale="2" value="#form.size#">
```

You can use this reference...

http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_18.html